# Erlang and Elixir

Tags: concurrency, erlang, elixir

SO community, just have a quick question to ask. I've been doing a bit of research on learning languages that have concurrency in mind. For the moment, I've been working with Scala and I've been loving it. I've decided to also learn some others, so as not to specialize in a particular language and instead learn as many as I can. So far, I've taken a keen liking to the EVM, specifically Elixir.

So, my question is this: how beneficial would it be for me to learn Erlang before learning Elixir? I'm very interested in the syntax and such of Elixir, but being built on Erlang, I'm not sure if it would hurt to jump straight into it.

Comment: That's kind of an open-ended question. You might be better off to ask it over on Programmers.Stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think learning Erlang would be *directly* useful for learning Elixir; learning what an atom looks like in Erlang isn't going to affect how you learn about atoms in Elixir, for example.

However, there's a lot more to Erlang than just Erlang the language.  The obvious one is OTP, which Elixir can make use of.  Now, there's no inherent reason that you can't learn OTP within the confines of Elixir, but Erlang's had years to accumulate documentation, tutorials, books, etc on the whole Erlang ecosystem, which is available to Elixir.  If you want to learn details of OTP, you might pick up the book *Erlang and OTP in Action*, but all the code there is Erlang.  If you know both Erlang and Elixir, it'd be a lot easier to apply what you've learned from the book to Elixir.

Or think of third-party tools written in Erlang.  These are useable by Elixir, but the documentation is very likely going to assume you're using Erlang, so again, knowing Erlang will help you apply what you learn to Elixir.

**EDIT by rvirding:**
I think you are wrong in your 1st paragraph as everything you would learn in Erlang is directly applicable to Elixir. All the data types are exactly the same and behave in exactly the same way which is what you would expect as they are what the underlying BEAM provides. So an Elixir atom and an Erlang atom are the **same** and are used in exactly the same way even if the syntax is (slightly) different. You have the same basic control structures and ways of organising code, in functions and modules, as again they are what the underlying BEAM provides. So while Elixir provides some extra high-level constructs underneath they are the same.

This what a bit too big for a comment, hence it ended up here.

Comment: @rvirding Agreed, and what I meant to imply was that learning Erlang _solely_ for the sake of Elixir is not necessary, not that knowing Erlang is unhelpful.  Basically, if your goal is Elixir, learning, for example, the syntax for an Erlang atom first isn't necessary, because you can just learn it in the context of Elixir.  However, if you _do_ know Erlang, it is indeed helpful.

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood you. No I agree, there is no reason as such to learn Erlang as a precursor to Elixir, but it is as you say that once you get deeper into the system you will not be able to avoid Erlang.

Comment: I would still learn Erlang before learning Elixir as I can relate things directly which will make my learning curve for elixir short and better. Also, While developing any good application you will　use third party libraries and most of them will be written in Erlang which you will add in your project. What you are saying is correct that Its not necessary to learn Erlang to learn Elixir but if you want to do serious programming then definitely it is the way to go about it. BTW I love Elixir :)

Comment: It makes more sense to learn Erlang once you run into a need for it.  If you never need it, then you've never wasted your time going down a rabbit trail.  If you need it, then you'll know what problems you're trying to solve and where to get started.  If you *want* to learn Erlang just for fun, then knock yourself out.  There's certainly value to it.  It's like learning Latin in order to learn Spanish: if you already know Latin then Spanish will be easier, but if your goal is to learn Spanish then adding preliminary steps just slows you down and delays achieving your goal.